# when I create a post request then Error occurs ..... the error = "error": "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

```
const ProductSchema={
name:{
    type: String
}} const Employee=mongoose.model('product',ProductSchema);catalogroute.post('/api/add catalogs', async(req,res)=>{
try{
    const user=new Employee({

        name:req.body.name
    });
   const val= await user.save();
    res.json(val);
   }
   catch(e){
       res.status(500).json({error: e.message});
   } } );
```

"error": "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')"

Comment: You should list all the technologies you are using, Like are you using an express server? If so you need to add body-parser. See how its hard to give you an anwser with to little information.

Answer (score 0):

In the post route, remove the space between add and catalogs, or use '/api/add-catalogs'.

Comment: still not working

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).